# Unreal Engine 4.26.1 - Connect multiple / more than one Generic USB Controllers

Tags: input, controller, usb, unreal-engine4, raw-input

I’m having a hard time trying to connect a steering wheel and pedals to the Unreal Engine (4.26.1). The steering wheel and the pedals are separated products, so each of them has its own USB connection. I’m using the plugin Windows RawInput to connect the devices as the GenericUSBController (see picture).

If I connect the devices **one at a time**, each device is recognized and works fine (either just the steering wheel or just the pedals). When both devices are connected to the computer **at the same time**, only the steering wheel works and the pedals don't work at all.

I’m afraid it’s because there is only one “slot” for GenericUSBControllers which is occupied by the steering wheel. I don’t have a chance to use different pedals or a different steering wheel.
Is there a way to connect more than one device via GenericUSBController? Or a way to “cast” the pedals to e.g. a Gamepad so it’s possible to use both devices at the same time?
I would be grateful, if someone has an idea how to fix this problem.

[Screenshot of the Input Axis Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGcGB.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the similar problems.

I used the WM Input manager to set them up as separate controllers, and mapped which controller to listen to for specific Axis.

https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/wm-input-manager

Hopefully it helps.